# Find the position of a word in a text and create an index that includes my words

Tags: mysql

The entire book is store in a personal cell. One book = one cell in the table. There are titles in the book, how do I find their position? The index for full-text search indicates the words position in the text.  I think this is what I am looking for.

Example

Table "My Books"

```
id  | Text (CLOB)              | author
-----------------------------------------------------
0   | For never was a story of | william shakespeare
    | more woe than this of    |
    | Juliet and her Romeo...  |
```

How to create an index with the words "Juliet" and "Romeo"?

Desired results

```
OFFSET  | WORD
-----------------
12      | Juliet
15      | Romeo
```

I am interested in any solution with similar job.